# client-server: client not receiving any data from the server

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, sockets, client

hello everyone i have this python code which sends live video feed from client to server, it worked perfectly until i have added the line where the server sends "hello" to the client while it is receiving the live feed, it stopped working.
the client uses multithreading one for receiving and one for sending the live feed.
any help on how to work that out please?.

here is my server code:

```
import socket, cv2, pickle, struct
import threading
import pyshine as ps

server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print('HOST IP:', host_ip)
port = 9999
socket_address = (host_ip, port)

print("Listening at", socket_address)
i=0

def show_client(addr, client_socket):
    try:
        print('CLIENT {} CONNECTED!'.format(addr))
        if client_socket:  # if a client socket exists
            data = b""
            payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
            while True:
                while len(data) < payload_size:
                    packet = client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)  # 4K
                    if not packet: break
                    data += packet
                packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
                data = data[payload_size:]
                msg_size = struct.unpack("Q", packed_msg_size)[0]

                while len(data) < msg_size:
                    data += client_socket.recv(4 * 1024)
                frame_data = data[:msg_size]
                data = data[msg_size:]
                frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
                text = f"CLIENT: {addr}"
                frame = ps.putBText(frame, text, 10, 10, vspace=10, hspace=1, font_scale=0.7,
                                    background_RGB=(255, 0, 0), text_RGB=(255, 250, 250))
                cv2.imshow(f"FROM {addr}", frame)
                client_socket.sendall('hello')  # send back to client

                key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                if key == ord('q'):
                    break
            client_socket.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"CLINET {addr} DISCONNECTED")
        pass

server_socket.bind(socket_address)
server_socket.listen()

while True:
    client_socket, addr = server_socket.accept()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=show_client, args=(addr, client_socket))
    thread.start()
    print("TOTAL CLIENTS ", threading.activeCount() - 1)
```

and here is my client code :

```
import socket,cv2, pickle,struct
import imutils # pip install imutils
import threading
import sys

camera = True
if camera == True:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
else:
    vid = cv2.VideoCapture('resources/video3.mp4')
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host_ip = '192.168.100.22' # Here according to your server ip write the address
i=1
port = 9999
client_socket.connect((host_ip,port))
def sendvid():

    while True:
        try:
            if client_socket:
                while True:
                    try:
                        img, frame = vid.read()
                        frame = imutils.resize(frame,width=380)
                        a = pickle.dumps(frame)
                        message = struct.pack("Q",len(a))+a
                        client_socket.sendall(message)
                        #print(client_socket.recv(16))
                        cv2.imshow(f"TO: {host_ip}",frame)
                        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
                        if key == ord("q"):
                            client_socket.close()

                    except:
                        print('VIDEO FINISHED!')
                        break
    

def recv():
    while True:
        print('client_socket.recv(16)')
        print(client_socket.recv(16))

thread1 = threading.Thread(target=sendvid)
thread1.start()
print("hello")
thread2 = threading.Thread(target=recv)
thread2.start()
```

Comment: If your problem is about transmitting data only, you could shorten your example without the face data, to try to debug and show us simple example. It will be easier to debug. See MRE here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sure and done, thx.